# Application on User Profile

Tags: facebook, user-profile

I have developed some Page Tab based application for Facebook.
I have also developed a canvas based application for Facebook.

How to put my Application in User's Profile page ?
(beside the Page tab or in the Canvas Page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not absolutely clear what you're asking here but if you're asking can you add an app as a tab to a user profile, the answer is no.